# How to set kvm to use router's dhcp in linux?

Tags: networking, linux-networking, ip, kvm-virtualization, dhcp

I'm new to kvm and my question may be obvious to some. How to use the local router dhcp instead the kvm local dhcp. The local dhcp has a range starting from 192.168.122.1 and i need it to use the local router with a range starting from 192.168.100.1. How to configure it? Thanks in advance!

My /etc/libvirt/qemu/networks/default.xml

```
    <network>
      <name>default</name>
      <uuid>21f9eef3-c1ac-49a1-b413-574011a2c4d5</uuid>
      <forward mode='nat'/>
      <bridge name='virbr0' stp='on' delay='0'/>
      <mac address='52:54:00:38:20:3e'/>
      <ip address='192.168.122.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
        <dhcp>
          <range start='192.168.122.45' end='192.168.122.55'/>
          <host mac='52:54:00:05:d8:ba' name='pluto' ip='192.168.122.50'/>
          <host mac='52:54:00:84:bb:56' name='kali' ip='192.168.122.45'/>
        </dhcp>
      </ip>
    </network>
```

I've seen a suggestion in this post [KVM Networking - assign IP to each VM by outside DHCP](https://serverfault.com/questions/1108268/kvm-networking-assign-ip-to-each-vm-by-outside-dhcp) to edit this file with this snippet, but I'm not sure where to put it in the xml file:

```
        <interface type='bridge'>
          <mac address='52:54:00:1c:00:3a'/>
          <source bridge='br0'/>
          <model type='e1000e'/>
          <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x01' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
        </interface>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you'd need to do first is to put your hypervisor's network on a bridged interface that the VMs can connect to.

Let's say this is going to be `br0` and the current physical interface is `eth0`.

Any IP configuration you have on `eth0` should be moved to `br0`.

The way to do this is persistently depends on how you configure your network and that differs even on the same distro (NetworkManager, netplan, systemd-networkd, classic distro scripts - all have different configuration).

If you wanted to do this once on the command line to try it out the below may work, and if you mess it up, a reboot would put your configuration back:

```
brctl addbr br0
ip a flush eth0
ip a add a.b.c.d/xx dev br0
brctl addif br0 eth0
ip link set br0 up
```

Then you can either attach a new network to your VM which is on the bridge (this can be done while the VM is running), or change the current interface (this would require a shutdown of the VM).

In general, all this is much easier if you use `virt-manager` - there is a GUI that makes the whole experience very easy.

Otherwise, you can add a new network to your VM with:

```
virsh attach-interface --domain your-vm-name \
  --type bridge \
  --source br0 \
  --model virtio \
  --config \
  --live
```

Here, `--live` will add the configuration to the running machine, and `--config` would persist it to its XML file so it is there after your shutdown the VM.

Alternatively, you can `virsh edit your-vm-name` and edit the network configuration you have now to mimic the one you posted (replace the current `<interface>...</interface>` so it is type bridge, source br0. You can keep the model and mac, and pci information as it is.

Comment: Thanks for the attention,  I've tried the first approach and I couldn't figure out what info to insert in this line   ip a add a.b.c.d/xx dev br0, is the ip of me vm or the ip range of the dhcp server, or else? I've created a second interface in my server but, probably because my mistake, It didn't worked. Later today I'll try the second approach, if the first is not fit for this case.

Comment: If your server currently has single interface eth0 with IP address 192.168.99.9/24, then this IP address should be assigned to the bridge (br0), and eth0 should be attached to the bridge. If you put the output of `ip a` to your question and indicate the DHCP interface and network, it will be easier to update the answer.